# SSRS Math across matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a matrix with the groupings below in SSRS 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

MembershipStatus has "New Enroll", "Term", "Active".

What I need to do is to add a row called "Other" to do the following calculation:

```
Last month new enroll + last month active – this month term – this month active
```

In the example below, it's

```
19,281 + 0 - 2,082 - 17,195 = 4
```

I've used temp tables and various combinations of APPLY to get the results I need in SQL, but due to the large number of parameter combinations, I really need to do it inside SSRS.

Should I just give up and code it in the CODE section of the report?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

[image: image for grouping and report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ReportItems function. Each text box in SSRS will have unique name which can be found by selecting the respective text box and then checking the top most section in the properties window displayed on the right side.

Let's say your NEW ENROLL value for June is displayed in Textbox1, TERM FOR June in Textbox2, ACTIVE for June in Textbox3, NEW ENROLL FOR July in Textbox4, TERM for July in Textbox5, ACTIVE FOR July in Textbox6 and so on. Write the below expression for OTHER value for July as below:

```
=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value + ReportItems!Textbox3.Value - ReportItems!Textbox5.Value - ReportItems!Textbox6.Value
```

This formula will change based on the default naming by SSRS for the respective textboxes.

Comment: Will test once I get back to the office.

Answer (score 0):

With the calculation provided, it only allows to do the calculation in the same month. The question is how to calculate numbers in the previous month against current month...
how could it be done?